Pixel checkered blur background like on Instagram
Instagram has such feature- when you click and hold on image, app launches dialog(or something similar) view to display image. But as you can see in attached image , it has nice, interesting background.
1.Blurred (open to discussion)
2.checkered in pixel by pixel style
I have been searching and trying to achieve this same effect.
No luck yet.
Any suggestions?


Looks like a custom shader (probably written in GLSL). Search on pixelate/pixelation. However each 'pixelated' block also looks like a gradient or other function has been applied so that the block is not uniform in color.

You can check the following resources

https://source.android.com/docs/core/display/window-blurs
How to blur background images in Android


It still doesn't explain the "checkered" blur

check the Below Library it's easy to implement the Blur effect.
https://github.com/mmin18/RealtimeBlurView

already tried all known blur libs.
None of them are close to "checkered" effect
